# Comparing browser request to directories

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to compare customer names to names in C:\ftp\ to make sure they exist. I am having trouble with my if statement. I think I need to convert my array to a string but I'm not sure how. I am new to programming here is what I have:

```
    protected bool customerCheck()
    {
        bool returnvalue = false;

        // check if costumer exist
        string[] files = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\ftp\");

        if (Request["ftpload"] == files)
        {
            returnvalue = true;
        }



        return returnvalue;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare a `string` to an *array* of `string`s. This can't work.

You need to check if the wanted string is present in the array.

Something like:

```
if (files.Contains(Request["ftpload"]))
```

Or a loop:

```
foreach(string file in files)
{
   if(file == Request["ftpload"])
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want to be even more concise, just say `return files.Contains(Request["ftpload"]);`. No need for the if statement.

Comment: @Omada - In this case, I try to optimize for the OP and try to ensure he understands the issue and solution/s.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I understand.

Comment: I understand. I am new to C# and I was not aware of the Contains function. Well done Omada.